# Indexing urls with hash #!

Tags: ajax, seo, indexing

I have a doubt with AJAX and crawlers.

For example if I have an url, and I have also this url/#!test with it has different content.

Then my question is

when I search for this page in google, introducing content of /#!test page, what will index
url (without the hash) or url/#!test ?

Answer (score 0):

You could define that within you html.

It is described [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) (Section 3)

Comment: yes I read that, but the doubt I have is becaouse of that page, but the question is, if I use page with hashes, when I search my web I google, he will show me the url with the hash or without?

For example, if my page is some kind o book with it have an Index, to look for every section, when i search this web in google i do not want that google show me example.com#chapter4 instead example.com

Comment: I am not good at english, but if I use `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` then I will have that I want? (my web is not static page)